# Solution for editing and sending PDF invoices?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, pdf, invoice-pdf

What would be the easiest solution to edit the design of a PDF invoice and send it to customers?

As I understand, editing the design in Magento is a bit too complicated.

I'm currently considering 2 options:

1. using third-party modules;
2. interating with Zoho Invoices (or similar service) where I can easily edit the design and send emails

It's Magento 2.4.1.

Thanks!

Comment: Use Zoho Books to send invoice. There API documentation is quite good. I also integrated zoho books in magento 2. One suggestion i can give you don't run API codes on checkout success observer or any other event it will make the process very slow. for example if your want to run API codes after order success you need to write code that will trigger API, from my personal experience it will make your checkout process very slow. instead of adding codes on custom event use https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-webhook/ and fire custom script. better read the documentation

Comment: I highly reccomend: https://fooman.com/magento-extension-pdf-customiser-m2.html

Comment: Hi guys! Thanks a lot! Integrating over Mageplaza Webhooks sounds nice (and free). Will try it. PDF customiser looks also nice but will try integrating with Zoho Books first as I need it anyway.